# JasperReports: Parameters or Fields?

Tags: java, jasper-reports

I was wondering if there are any performance benefits (or other benefits) to filling a JasperReport with fields values instead of parameters.

For instance, say I want to populate a pie chart with 10 pie slices.

What benefits - if any - are there to setting the pie's expressions to:

```
JRDesignExpression key = new JRDesignExpression("$F{PieSlice}.key");
JRDesignExpression label = new JRDesignExpression("$F{PieSlice}.label");
JRDesignExpression value = new JRDesignExpression("$F{PieSlice}.value");
```

...as opposed to this:

```
Map<String,String> params = new HashMap<String,String>();
params.put("pie-slice-key-01", "foo");
params.put("pie-slice-label-01", "Foo");
params.put("pie-slice-value-01", .25);
// ... etc.

JasperPrint print = JasperFillManager.fill(jasperDesign, params);

// ...

JRDesignExpression key = new JRDesignExpression("$P{pie-slice-key-01}");
JRDesignExpression label = new JRDesignExpression("$P{pie-slice-label-01}");
JRDesignExpression value = new JRDesignExpression("$P{pie-slice-value-01}");

JRDesignExpression key = new JRDesignExpression("$P{pie-slice-key-02}");
JRDesignExpression label = new JRDesignExpression("$P{pie-slice-label-02}");
JRDesignExpression value = new JRDesignExpression("$P{pie-slice-value-02}");

// ...etc.
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The fields are the data from datasource, parameteres can be calculated (expression) or can be external data that define the report behaviour. Parameter is like a method argument, for example in java.

Comment: You can read this tutorial: http://jasperforge.org/uploads/publish//jasperreportswebsite/JR%20Website/jasperreports_tutorial.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think there is any benefit. It's just a semantic difference. A field comes from the data source, and is supposed to be put in the details band, which will be repeated for every element in the data source. A parameter has a unique value, global to the whole report.

So, if you must repeat the pie chart for every row of a resultset (or bean of a collection), use fields. If you just have one global pie chart in your report, use parameters.